# Gnuplot: position of key elements

Tags: gnuplot

With

```
set key left top
```

I can set the position of the legend. However, I would like to set each title separately in such a way, that in the following example the legend is on one line: left the first and right the second one.

```
plot sin(x) title "Sinus", x title "X"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uset the horizontal keyword

```
set key horizontal top left
```